# Prove (A$\Delta$B)$\Delta$(B$\Delta$C) = A$\Delta$C where A$\Delta$B = (A\B) ∪ (B\A)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

It looked like a smple reduction problem, but it seems not to be the way once you beging proving one side to be subset of the other, it turns on a big mess, I´m hoping someone can see a more elegant solution like a transivity property or something.

Comment: Hint: Use Venn diagram

Comment: Graphic solutions are not allowed as proof, I know the property holds, but cannot find a formal and pertinent short way to write it :(.

Comment: This is a common exercise. Yes, it is a bit messy, but certainly doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have associativity of $\Delta$; and if you know that for any set $S$,  $S\Delta S=\emptyset$; and $S\Delta\emptyset=S$, the result follows quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Use indicator function.

Recall the symmetric difference has $1_{A\triangle B}(x)=1_A(x)+1_B(x)$ for all $x$, where the sum is taken mod 2.  So
$$
\begin{align*}
1_{(A\triangle B)\triangle(B\triangle C)}
&=1_{A\triangle B}+1_{B\triangle C}\\
&=1_A+1_B+1_B+1_C\\
&=1_A+1_C\\
&=1_{A\triangle C}
\end{align*}
$$